getRoleNames method as an accessor in user model. Spatie Laravel Permission
I am trying to create an accessor that will return the users role name. It is possible to access the getRoleNames() method in the User model?
//User Model

/**
     * The accessors to append to the model's array form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $appends = [
        'role_name',
    ];

/**
     * Ge the user's role name.
     * 
     * @return Attribute
     */
    public function roleName(): Attribute
    {
        return Attribute::make(
            get: function () {
                $user = User::find($this->id);
                
                return $user->getRoleNames();
            },
        );
    }

I tried to make it as an accessor but it returns null

get: fn() => $this->getRoleNames(),?

You need to add following trait in your User model.
class User extends Authenticatable
{
   use HasRoles;

   // Other model code
   
   // For single role
   public function getRoleNameAttribute()
   {
     return $this->roles->pluck('name')->first();
   }
   
   // For Multiple
   public function getRoleNamesAttribute()
   {
     return $this->roles->pluck('name')->toArray();
   }
}

Then you can access it easily in your controller like.
$user = User::find(1);
$roleName = $user->role_name; // for single
$roleNames = $user->role_names; // for multiple

